# Does HtmlService.createHtmlOutput in google apps script change the string / what does it do / add

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

Alessandro.
Thanks for coming back to me. Through some fairly tedious investigation I have tracked down the chunk of javascript that appears to be causing the problem. It appears to be a problem that the structure a google apps script wraps round the provided code stops it working. 
The offending item is script that highlights a button when the mouse hovers over it. I have just deleted this feature from my code, because its really only a nice to have, but I would like to understand why it does not work so I don't fall over it again and waste more time in the future.

To re-iterate the impact before I share the code.

Scenario A - javascript does not include this code - the html works in both circumstances

1. In the https://www.w3schools.com/ "TryIt" area and when saved as a local html file (download from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_o3oXoFnWDRNkAbLUhxpkEsMXe73kHHr)  - AND
2. When the code is read as a block from a cell in a google sheet and delivered from a google apps script web app bound to the spreadsheet (click https://script.google.com/a/macros/goringgapu3a.org.uk/s/AKfycbwC0aWNo0lfy3TrLzYGW4U0Sd0VijdZ6rVqQtjVNf49mM-8Dz8/exec?show=without_hide to see the result)

Scenario B - javascript does include this code - the html does not work when delivered by a web app.
 1. Works in the https://www.w3schools.com/ "TryIt" area and when saved as a local html file (download from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ty1avr1p7o0qgyZDGAgMlHsG9aTfJuOh)  - BUT
 2. DOES NOT WORK when the code is read as a block from a cell in a google sheet and delivered from a google apps script web app bound to the spreadsheet (click https://script.google.com/a/macros/goringgapu3a.org.uk/s/AKfycbwC0aWNo0lfy3TrLzYGW4U0Sd0VijdZ6rVqQtjVNf49mM-8Dz8/exec?show=with_hide to see the result)

The offending piece of javascript is

```
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
this.className += " active";
});
}
```

The google sheet can be viewed here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qN7BYMAwjKQLqgOll8HPnAClJnsvhsqL9n-aMst2xT8/edit?usp=sharing

In the tab called HTML there is a formula that concatenates all the HTML from the same column in the data tab =substitute(substitute(concatenate(data!A:A),"('","(*****"),"')","*****)"). This is included because otherwise certain positions of ' end up splitting the input. The web app script that delivers the web page reverses this - the code is shown below (n.b. the string logged is exactly the same as the one in the google sheet, so this bit seems to work OK).

```
function doGet(e){
  var params = JSON.stringify(e);
  var show = e.parameters.show;
  Logger.log(params);


var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var ws = ss.getSheetByName('HTML');
var colnum = 0;
if(show=="without_hide"){colnum = 1};
if(show=="with_hide"){colnum = 2};
Logger.log(colnum);

var lookedup = ws.getRange(2, colnum).getValue();

 while(lookedup.indexOf("(*****") >0){
 lookedup = lookedup.replace("(*****","('");
 };

  while(lookedup.indexOf("*****)") >0){
 lookedup = lookedup.replace("*****)","')");
 };
 Logger.log("length" + lookedup.length);
 Logger.log("zz = " + lookedup);

 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(lookedup);
 };
```

I have previously used Awesome tables to show google sheet data in a frame in a new google sites, but they now want to charge $600 pa for it - we are a small charity and I am an amateur developing a new web site. So I developed a hack that takes the data in the sheet and turns it into a string of html, which is then read by an apps script and delivered by a web app. This means non web people can edit the data in the sheets and the html and web page is updated automatically.
I have now developed a few of these and they work well, except the my current one. The only issue I have come across is with e.g.('something'), so I substitute the (' and ') in the sheet and reverse it in the script.

In this one, the html works fine if you copy it and paste it into a document, saved as type html, but not if read by the script and delivered by the web app.
The length of string suplied to HtmlService.createHtmlOutput is the same as the length of the string in the sheet. If the string is copied from the log and pasted into a new html document, it works fine.

Does anyone know if HtmlService.createHtmlOutput changes the string, or is sensitive to specific characters / tell what it actually does?

Grateful for any hints / can share code and html if it helps
Tearing my hair out with this - although I worked in IT all my career, I was never a programmer and am now retired and doing this to keep my brain going!
Thanks

Comment: Caja Sanitation

Comment: Please share your code and show how the HTML is being modified.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was a bug in the script for the WebApp that doesn't work.

Here the script for the ones that works:

```
filterSelection("all");
function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
}
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
            element.className += " " + arr2[i];
        }
     }
}
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
             arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
```

Here it's the one which doesn't:

```
filterSelection("all");
function filterSelection(c) {
    var x, i;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
    if (c == "all") c = "";
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
        if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
    }
}
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
            element.className += " " + arr2[i];
        }
     }
}
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
    var i, arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
    arr2 = name.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
        while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
             arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
        }
    }
    element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}
></body></html> //SYTNAX ERROR
```

So the script won't run and the click handler will throw an exception. I don't know if this is an error when building the template, but running the script in the browser console will make your page work so this is the problem.